# Using Jackson to deserialize with Lombok builder

Tags: java, json, jackson, lombok

#### The Question

[Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder)'s `@builder` annotation creates a [builder-class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) for a class. To support deserialization of json items (using [Jackson's ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html)), I've added the following annotations:

```java
@Builder
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Item.ItemBuilder.class)
@JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix="")
public class Item {
    @Getter
    String partitionvalue;
}
```

This is based on the `@Jacksonized` [documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Jacksonized). On the usage of the deserializer, upon a json file which is stored in [AWS S3 bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3.html) and its content is simply: `{"partitionvalue": "test"}`, my code is:

```java
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain())
            .withRegion(region)
            .build();
S3Object s3Object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucket, key));
Item item = objectMapper.readValue(s3Object.getObjectContent(), Item.class);
```

However when running on a json file that  Jackson fails with the message:

```sh
Unrecognized field "partitionvalue" (class com.example.Test$TestBuilder),
 not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])
 at [Source: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3ObjectInputStream@2ca47471; line: 1, column: 21] (through reference chain: com.example.TestBuilder["partitionvalue"])
```

#### Extra Details

- Using @`Jacksonized` annotation directly didn't work as well, and since it is lombok-experimental I used the annotations I needed to use with builder directly.
- I verified that Lombok will do what I expect of a builder class by using "delombok" option in the Lombok IntelliJ plugin:

```java
public class Item {
    String partitionvalue;
    Item(String partitionvalue) {
        this.partitionvalue = partitionvalue;
    }
    public static ItemBuilder builder() {
        return new ItemBuilder();
    }
    public String getPartitionvalue() {
        return this.partitionvalue;
    }
    public static class ItemBuilder {
        private String partitionvalue;
        ItemBuilder() { }
        public Item.ItemBuilder partitionvalue(String partitionvalue) {
            this.partitionvalue = partitionvalue;
            return this;
        }
        public Item build() {
            return new Item(partitionvalue);
        }
        public String toString() {
            return "Item.ItemBuilder(partitionvalue=" + this.partitionvalue + ")";
        }
    }
}
```

- Without the `@Builder` annotation (and with adding `@NoArgsConstructor` +  `@AllArgsConstructor` + `@Setter`) it worked fine, so the problem isn't with the file from the S3 bucket or the way it is parsed.

Comment: BTW, I'm using Jackson version 2.6, Lombok version 1.8, Java SDK8.

Comment: This is awsome.  Didn't know it was possible. Cool.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`@JsonPOJOBuilder` has to be put on the builder class, not the class itself. Without `@Jacksonized`, you have to customize the generated builder class as follows:

```
@Builder
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Item.ItemBuilder.class)
public class Item {
    @Getter
    String partitionvalue;

    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix="")
    public static class ItemBuilder {}
}
```

Comment: thanks, that was resolutive for me

Answer (score 22):

Using lombok-1.18.16 (and .18) with the `@Jacksonized` annotation works for me. Without that annotation, I get the same error as you do.

```
@Builder
@Jacksonized
public class JsonizerItem {

    @Getter private String partitionvalue;

}
```

---

```
@Test
void test() throws JsonProcessingException {
    JsonizerItem item = new ObjectMapper().readValue("{ \"partitionvalue\" : \"test\"}", JsonizerItem.class);
    assertEquals("test", item.getPartitionvalue());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! however I chose @Jan Rieke answer as accepted answer because it supplied the reason that using the jacksonized internal annotations directly didn't work.