# Spring Boot - JSON deserialization of object with one attribute

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

could some one explain me why Spring Boot is not able to deserialize this JSON? Based on this [online validator](https://jsonlint.com/), it is valid JSON.

```json
{
    "name": "someName"
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
"Cannot construct instance of `com.znamenacek.debtor.dto.GroupDto$Request$Create` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)\n at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 2, column: 5]"
```

The class I am trying to serialize/deserialize is following:

```java
@Value @Builder(toBuilder = true) @ToString
        public static class Create{
            @NotBlank(message = "Name must be filled")
            String name;
        }
```

I have just discovered that it is accepting the value in this format:

```json
"someName"
```

To me it seems strange ...

Comment: That's exactly what jackson `@Value` annotation does. What did you expect? And it's really bad idea to use lombok `@Builder` annotation to your DTO classes

Comment: The @Value is not jackson's annotation, it is from lombok. BTW why it is bad idea to use builder?

Comment: Basically, anything that interfers with instantiation is bad idea when dealing with serialize/deserialize libraries such as jackson. You better limit lombok use for this class to just `@Data` - it generates getters/setters which are ok.

Comment: For builders, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982340/jackson-builder-pattern.
Edit, or this, more targeted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66399749/using-jackson-to-deserialize-with-lombok-builder